# ¿ Por que me queda hueco en una de las secciones?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy creando un sitio y una de las secciones no ocupa todo el alto, queda un pequeño hueco arriba y abajo.
Es en la sección penúltima la anterior al Copyright, es verde y se ven los huecos blancos.
Puse el  [ejemplo en CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/miguelitolaparra/pen/VymQbq) pues tengo mucho código y no me coge todo, no se crear los enlaces para bootstrap.
Gracias.

```css
body {
 padding-top: 50px;
 color: #959595;
 }
 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: black;
 }
 
.feature {
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 color: greenyellow;
 }
 
.article-intro {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-blurb {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    color: black;
}
    
.footer-blurb-item {
    padding: 30px;
    }
 
.small-print {
 background-color: #000000;
 padding: 40px 0;

}

.feature,
.page-intro,
.article-intro,
.footer-blurb,
.small-print {
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Template by Quackit.com -->
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Principal</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--CSS personalizado: puede usar esta hoja de estilo para anular cualquier estilo de Bootstrap y / o aplicar sus propios estilos  -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Fuentes y styles de area de compartir -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway+Dots" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/share-5.css">
         <!--/Fuentes y styles de area de compartir -->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                 Logo
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Casa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Servicios <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
       <li><a href="galeri_desbro/demo.html">Desbroces</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Vallados</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Podas y talas</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="formulario/formpage.html">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.es/maps/place/desbroces+y+limpieza+de+fincas/@40.2216441,-5.1430287,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd3f8b6555555555:0x52897d019c61a3cd!8m2!3d40.22164!4d-5.14084">Ubicacion</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>

    <!-- Search -->
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">buscar</button>
    </form>

            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

 <div class="jumbotron feature">
  <div class="container">
           
            <h1>Desbroces y limpieza de fincas:</h1>
   <p>Lleva a cabo el desbroce y limpieza mecanizada de todo tipo de terreno, eliminando cualquier especie de hierbas, maleza o matorral, 
                combatiendo efizcamente el riesgo de incendios en la época estival.</p>
            <h3 style="text-align:center;" >Trabajamos en toda España, si bien la mayoría de nuestros trabajos se centran en las provincias de Ávila, 
                Madrid, Segovia, Salamanca, Cáceres y Toledo.</h3>
   <!--<p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Engage Now</a></p>-->
  </div>
 </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container" >

        <!-- Page Intro -->
        <div class="row page-intro">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Nuestros clientes siempre satisfechos.
                    <small>Vea una muestra de nuestro trabajo</small>
                </h1>
                <p>Nos desplazamos a cualquier parte de España para hacer su proyecto realidad. Vea alguno de los últimos trabajos realizados, 
                    y descubrira nuestro compromiso y profesionalidad.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Feature Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/desbroce_img/desbro1.jpg" alt="Desbroces">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="galeri_desbro/demo.html">Desbroces</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Desbrozamos y limpiamos toda clase fincas, urbanas, forestales.... Contamos con una amplia gama de maquina para las peores condiciones de trabajo. 
                    Desbrozadoras manuales, de cadenas y de martillos </p>
            </article>
            <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" alt="Vallados">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="galeri_vallas.html">Vallados</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Cerramos su parcela con  malla de alambre. Vallamos su finca con postes de madera en gran cantidad de medidas y tratada para el paso del tiempo.
                    Tubo galvanizado, malla de simple torsion, malla ganadera...
                </p>
            </article>

            <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/forestal_img/fores14.jpg" alt="Trabajos forestales">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="galeri_forest/gale_fores.html">Trabajos forestales</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Talamos los arboles de su parcela urbana sin crear daños a edificios colindandantes, cuales quiera que sean las circunstancias. 
                    Hacemos limpia y entresaque de su bosque, haciendo una selección  con el rigor y profesionalidad que dan 30 años de experiencia.</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
 
 <footer>
  <div class="footer-blurb">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="images/podas_img/podando2.jpg" alt=""width="200" height="200" >
      <h3>Toda clase de podas</h3>
      <p>Profesionales de poda en toda clase de arboles: frutales, ornamentales, decorativos..., dandoles a sus arboles el vigor y la energía necesaria
                            para sacarles el mejor rendimiento.
                        </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="galeri_podas.html">Una muestra</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="images/caminos_img/camino1.jpg" alt=""width="200" height="200">
      <h3>Caminos de piedra</h3>
      <p>Arreglamos el viejo acceso a su finca. Creamos para usted un camino digno de la época romana para que se sorprendan las visitas a su chalet. 
                            Son muchos los proyectos que nos avalan...</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="galeri_caminos/galeri_caminos.html">Juzgue usted</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="images/caminos_img/pared3.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200">
      <h3>Muros de piedra</h3>
      <p>Expertos en la reparación de vancales, muros de piedra, que harán de su finca un lugar rustico y entrañable.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="galeri_muros/galeri_muros.html">Una muestra...</a></p>
     </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row --> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="content content-3">
                
                      
        
                            <section>
                                    <ul id="services">
                                        <h2 style="text-align:center;"> Comparta nuestro trabajo con sus amigos.</h2>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="facebook">
                                                <a  target="_blank"href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es&amp;t=Social%20Buttons%20in%20HTML%20only%20using%20Twitter%20Bootstrap%203%20and%20Font%20Awesome%20Icons">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>Facebook</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="twitter">
                                                <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es&amp;text=Social%20Buttons%20in%20HTML%20only%20using%20Twitter%20Bootstrap%203%20and%20Font%20Awesome%20Icons">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>Twitter</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="youtube">
                                                <a target="_blank" href="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&amp;url=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>Google+</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="linkedin">
                                                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>LinkedIn</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="instagram">
                                                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/colorlib">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>Instagram</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="github">
                                                <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/puikinsh/">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>Github</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                            
                                </section>
                                
                    
                
            </section>
        <div class="small-print">
         <div class="container">
          <p><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="formulario/formpage.html">Contacto</a></p>
          <p>Copyright &copy; miguel-espeso 2017</p>
         </div>
        </div>
 </footer>


 
</body>
<!--&amp;  para indicar el simbolo-->
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien la respuesta anterior soluciono tu problema, mi respuesta es para que entiendas donde esta el error.

La etiqueta **h2** donde está el título, **tiene un margin-top que es el que está empujando la franja verde hacia abajo**, ya que sobresale del contenedor y el espacio de abajo es porque **la lista "services" es un UL y tiene un margen abajo por defecto.**

Para solucionar efectivamente esto, solo debías agregar un padding y modificar un margin en la lista con id "*services*":

```
section #services {
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Aunque lo importante es que ya lo solucionaste. Buen día.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto amigo:

Solo cree una nueva clase en tus estilos:

```
  .social{
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color:#77CC6D;
}
```

Y la agregue en la etiqueta **section**:

```
<section class="social">
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas,  saludos.

Comment: Le añadi 40px en vez de 30px y funciona perfectamente @A.Palacio , gracias

Comment: De nada para eso estamos , saludos.